# How to fix the ERROR PACKAGE com.mysql does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How to fix this program?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager; 
import java.sql.SQLException;

class MySqlData {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbcDriver());
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test/user=root&password=merimaa");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("Select * from employee");
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(res.getString("employee_name"));
        }
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure you have the MySQL jar file in your $CLASSPATH

Comment: where does the error come?  At compile time?  and what exactly is the error?  please improve the question so others can answer it

Answer (score 2):

As other people have put:

- Your code is fine
- Your error is related to classpath issues
- Download the MySQL java libraries
- http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html
- **Read the documentation** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j.html

Comment: I don't think the code is fine, throwing `Exception` is in mosts cases not the ideal way to find errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add appropriate jar file that contains sql driver to your classpath

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download a mysql driver, next set up some exception catchers arround the connection with the mysql, or throw some exception.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to download the MySQL Connector.

Download it from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

and drop it in your project folder

Answer (score 0):

Add Jar file to  WEB-INF/lib.

Use below

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 


 try {
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://host/db";
            Connection connection = null; 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "username", "password");
            if(!connection.isClosed())
                 out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
            connection.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            out.println("Unable to connect to database"+ex);
        }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13506117/876739