# Unknown issue with MySQL Driver not found

Tags: java, mysql

I am successfully able to connect a simple java application which prints out all the data by declaring it appropriate and imported the MySQL connector jar file into the project. However, the issue is when I want to connect to MySQL through a web application(glassfish). I have imported the MySQL connector jar file  and declared it appropriately but I don't understand why the driver isn't being found.

The following is the error that I am receiving:

```js
2016 - 01 - 29T16: 22: 25.873 + 0000 | Info: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java: 1783)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java: 1633)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java: 187)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java: 125)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java: 264)
at org.apache.jsp.validate_jsp._jspService(validate_jsp.java: 56)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java: 111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java: 790)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java: 411)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java: 473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java: 377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java: 790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java: 1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java: 318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java: 160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java: 734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java: 673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java: 99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java: 174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java: 416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java: 283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java: 459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java: 167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java: 206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java: 180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java: 235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java: 119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java: 283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java: 200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java: 132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java: 111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java: 77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java: 536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java: 112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java: 117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java: 56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java: 137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java: 591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java: 571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java: 745)
```

Validate.jsp

```js
<% @page language = "java"
contentType = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding = "ISO-8859-1" %>
  < !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" >
<% @page import = "java.sql.*" %>
  <%
  try {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String driver = ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Class.forName(driver); // MySQL database connection
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ebooking" + "user=user&password=user");
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from student where stu_username=? and stu_password=?");
    pst.setString(1, username);
    pst.setString(2, password);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next())
      out.println("Valid login credentials");
    else
      out.println("Invalid login credentials");
  } catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
  out.println("Something went wrong !! Please try again");
} %>
```

Comment: Place your `mysql-jdbc-connector.jar` under lib folder in the tomcat.

Comment: @STaefi I'm not usinfg tomcat. I'm using glassfish.

Comment: Ok glassfish has a lib folder too. All the classes and jar files there, are load when the server is started. `GLASSFISH_HOME_DIR/glassfish/lib`

Comment: @STaefi Thank you so much. That has worked. Its all about getting experience on fixing small issues like this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have added the [mysql library](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) file into library

also

add a `?` before user

change:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ebooking" + "user=user&password=user");
```

to

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ebooking" + "?user=user&password=user");
```

Answer (score 0):

Any JDBC api call requires suitable jdbc driver supported by underlying database.

Please check your application WAR file that it has jdbc driver of MYSQL database.

ClassNotFoundException will occur, if the jar is not loaded in your classloader of JVM

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the method getConnection. This method is waiting for three arguments.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class JavaConnect {
    public static void ImportDriver() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection ConnectDB() {   
        Connection connection = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ebooking";
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "user");
            return connection;
        } 
            catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Please try again !");
        } 

        return connection;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you ! Have a good day !

Comment: Okay I see but how would I implement this as all my workings are in the jsp?

Comment: Look this post if you still haven't found  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505833/connecting-mysql-from-jsp

Answer (score 0):

Try to  write the connection string adding  maybe a `port` and `ebooking?` instead of `ebooking`like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/ebooking?" +
                               "user=user&password=user");
```

And don't forgit to add available `jdbc driver`.