# JSP Example to connect to MySQL database and retrieve records

Tags: mysql, jsp, netbeans, nullpointerexception, wampserver

I am new to jsp and was trying to display some data from my db `test1`, which I have created it in `wampserver`.

I have installed NetBeans for jsp, wampserver to create a db and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar`. Jar file I have downloaded and added to folder Libraries in NetBeans.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");%>

String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1";
```

The error is,

> exception  org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException root cause
> java.lang.NullPointerException

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Usually we need a username and password to connect to the database. Do U have that in your Jsp as well?

Comment: Your url link has the db url

Comment: Does this help: [Connecting MySQL from JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505833/connecting-mysql-from-jsp)

Comment: Please add full stack trace and code snippet to the question. In case of NullPointerException, it'll be helpful to know where this exception occurs.