# java: package com.mysql.cj.jdbc does not exist Spring Boot Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm very new to development, and I'm attempting to run an old project on my local machine. However, when I try to run it, I encounter the error message: "java: package com.mysql.cj.jdbc does not exist." I have configured Java 1.8 in the Project Structure settings, as well as in the Edit Configuration, since it was the version used by the previous developer. Any guidance or assistance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.kv.pg.instanceManager;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.kv.pg.commons.helper.PropertiesLoader;
import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource;

public class DBManager{

private static volatile DBManager INSTANCE = null;

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBManager.class);

private DBManager()
{
    setUpDataSourceInContext();
}

public static DBManager getInstance()
{
    if (INSTANCE == null)
    {
        synchronized (DBManager.class)
        {
            if (INSTANCE == null)
            {
                INSTANCE = new DBManager();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public DataSource getDataSource()
{
    DataSource dataSource = null;

    try
    {
        InitialContext iniCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) iniCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/");
        Object obj = envCtx.lookup("jdbc/PGIMDB");
        if (obj != null)
        {
            dataSource = (DataSource) obj;
        }
        if (dataSource == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to find data source, please check database configurations.");
        }
    } catch (Exception exp)
    {
        logger.error("Error Getting Data Source" + exp.getMessage(), exp);
        dataSource = null;
    }
    return dataSource;
}

public Connection getConnection()
{
    Connection conn = null;
    try
    {
        DataSource dataSource = getDataSource();
        if (dataSource != null)
        {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        }
    } catch (Exception exp)
    {
        logger.error("Error Getting Connection" + exp.getMessage(), exp);
        // throw exp;
        conn = null;
    }
    return conn;
}

/*
 * public void close() { // DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn, stmt, rs); }
 */

@Bean
private DataSource getMySQLDataSource()
{
    Properties props = null;

    MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource ds = null;
    try
    {
        logger.info("DataSourceFactory Try loading Database Properties");

        props = PropertiesLoader.load("im.db.properties");

        logger.debug("Properties Loaded::" + props);
        ds = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
        ds.setURL(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_URL"));
        ds.setUser(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"));
        ds.setPassword(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"));

    } catch (Exception exp)
    {
        logger.error("Error Creating DataSource" + exp.getMessage(), exp);
        throw exp;
    }
    return ds;
}

private void setUpDataSourceInContext()
{
    try
    {
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
        System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.apache.naming");
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        ic.createSubcontext("java:");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:comp");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:comp/env");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:comp/env/jdbc");

        ic.bind("java:comp/env/jdbc/PGIMDB", this.getMySQLDataSource());
    } catch (Exception exp)
    {
        logger.error("Error Binding DataSource To context" + exp.getMessage(), exp);
        // throw exp;
    }
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: can you share the maven `pom.xml` file or gradle build file

Comment: What Build System are u using? Maven or Gradle?

Comment: I am using Maven @Morty

Comment: @AndreiLisa I have updated it in the description

Comment: Why you dont use a starter to do connection with database instead of do it manually? I mean something like `spring-boot-data-jpa` or `spring-boot-jdbc`  it is more easy and increase development experience, great technologies for great peoples

Comment: @AndreiLisa I just started at a new company, and they're using these database connection technologies manually in a big project. It's working on other developers' end, but not on mine. I've been asked to fix this using the same implementation, and it's been one day with no progress.

Comment: ok, sure i am going to check and i will give a answer

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: @tgdavies I'm using intellij idea

Comment: Can we have the full error, please.

Comment: By the way, your linked Maven repo page note that the artifact has moved to: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j

Comment: By the way, [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.1/en/) for Connector/J strongly recommends moving from version 8.0.x to 8.1.x for use with MySQL Server version 5.7, 8.0, and 8.1.

Comment: I am sure that you don't have my sql driver on classpath, answers from this question can help you [-error-package-com-mysql-does-not-exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641076/how-to-fix-the-error-package-com-mysql-does-not-exist)

Comment: @AndreiLisa can you please share a link or resource where class path is being set ? I tried doing it but didn't find any help